# mysql shows carriage returns but nl2br doesn't maintain them

Tags: php, mysql, nl2br

I have text fields in the MySQL database that show in PHPMyAdmin as having line breaks or carriage returns. However when displaying that text field on a web page, they aren't there.

I have tried nl2br(). I have tried str_replace on \n \r \r\n & \v. All with no luck.

The original data came from a Filemaker database. I can't work out what is giving the carriage return.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
This is a straight copy and paste of a sample from the database field but from what I can tell, it won't transition to this comment field 100% identical. But here goes:

```
2010 Telecommunications - technical/internal brochure2004 Foodtown Catalogue and Banner2001 Alliance Group Holdings Annual Report2001 Cover of Company Profile2000 Clear Communications Mailout
```

In the text field in database this appears like this:

```
2010 Telecommunications - technical/internal brochure
2004 Foodtown Catalogue and Banner
2001 Alliance Group Holdings Annual Report
2001 Cover of Company Profile
```

Comment: What does the source look like. Can you post some data/code??

Comment: What does [`SELECT HEX(field_with_linebreaks)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) return?

Comment: The best I can tell, the hex value of the character is 0B. Which seems to be \v???

Comment: Are you using `str_replace` with double quotes or single ones?

Comment: 0x0B apparently is a vertical tab, whatever that means ;-) You should be fine with $text=str_replace(chr(0x0B), '<br>', $text); - Question is why did someone store the text in that way.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel you are a legend. I hadn't used chr() before. Thank you. In answer to why text was stored that way? All I can say is Filemaker...

Answer (score 0):

use

```
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but didn't do it sorry.